# Large dynamic side-nav menus using PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

What is the best way to display a large tree side-nav menu with many nested list levels using PHP and MySQL?

How many tables should I use and how should I code the PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very good article written by Gijs Van Tulder
[Storing Hierarchical Data in a Database](http://articles.sitepoint.com/print/hierarchical-data-database)

> Whether you want to build your own
>   forum, publish the messages from a
>   mailing list on your Website, or write
>   your own cms: there will be a moment
>   that you'll want to store hierarchical
>   data in a database. And, unless you're
>   using a XML-like database, tables
>   aren't hierarchical; they're just a
>   flat list. You'll have to find a way
>   to translate the hierarchy in a flat
>   file.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna check this question: [Generating many nested lists using PHP and MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620505/generating-many-nested-lists-using-php-and-mysql) - I suspect that you are the author of both :)

Comment: No I'm not the author of both, but I will check out the article though.

Comment: Does not explain the PHP issue though.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to take a look at my nested set article: http://www.fliquidstudios.com/2008/12/23/nested-set-in-mysql/

You really don't need to do anything special on the PHP side of things because all the grunt work is done in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

table Menu (id, parent_menu_id, item_id, menu_text); 
table Item (id, item_text, ...);
write your own loop to descend through the menu hierarchy starting where parent_menu_id is null.